# How to access tkinter default symbolic color names?

Tags: python, tkinter

The default symbolic color names recognized by Tk are given [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm). How can I access it in Tk or tkinter?

The available color commands in Tk are `Tk.colormapwindows()` and `Tk.wm_colormapwindows`, but these methods aren't what I am looking for.

Linux has a default list of symbolic colors in `/etc/X11/rgb.txt`. I have tried to u them but discovered that there can be incompatibilities with tkinter, and I get error e.g.`_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "ghost"`

Comment: not sure I understand your question; the common use is as a kwarg, something line `color='light blue'`, or `color='LightGoldenrod4'`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I would like to create a list comprising the default symbolic color names of Tk. So far, I have found 12 symbolic color names of Linux that Tk do not recognised. The valid list of symbol color names is to ensure valid  symbolic color names are supplied to my tkinter application.